# ServiceStack client on a Xamarin.iOS project

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, servicestack

I am trying to use the ServiceStack clients on a Xamarin iOS project and when debugging it I have the following exception:

> “System.ArgumentException: PclExport.Instance needs to be
>   initialized”.

The code that produces the exception is the following:

```
try
    {

        string strReadParam = this.xmlParser.GetString("SyncUrl");
        CommonStatic.SyncWSUrl = strReadParam;

        var client = new JsonServiceClient(CommonStatic.SyncWSUrl);
        client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5, 0);
        var response = client.Get(new mSalesCheckConnectionRequest { DBSource = CommonStatic.DBSource, DBSourceInstance = CommonStatic.DBSourceInstance, DBName = CommonStatic.DBName, DBUsername = CommonStatic.DBUsername, DBPassword = CommonStatic.DBPassword });

        return;

    }
    catch (System.Net.WebException wex)
    {
    }
```

I am using ServiceStack.Interfaces, ServiceStack.Client.Pcl and ServiceStack.Text.Pcl all having version 4.0.34. Additionally I referenced Newtonsoft.Json at version 6.0.7.

After some research I realized that the PCL provider for iOS is not registered automatically, so I added “IosPclExportClient.Configure();” before instantiating the new Json Service Client and a I referenced ServiceStack.Pcl.iOS.dll at version 4.0.0.0.

The result is the following error: 
“Cannot include both 'monotouch.dll' and 'Xamarin.iOS.dll' in the same Xamarin.iOS project - 'Xamarin.iOS.dll' is referenced explicitly, while 'monotouch.dll' is referenced by 'ServiceStack.Pcl.iOS, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.”

Is there is any suggestion of resolving this problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7):

You need to call `IosPclExportClient.Configure();` when you application starts to initialise the PCL Export Client before use in iOS applications.

So in your `Main` method:

```cs
static void Main (string[] args)
{
    // Configure ServiceStack Client
    IosPclExportClient.Configure();

    // Set AppDelegate
    UIApplication.Main (args, null, "AppDelegate");
}
```

> and a I referenced ServiceStack.Pcl.iOS.dll at version 4.0.0.0.

The PCL specific NuGet packages of ServiceStack are no longer maintained, as they have been merged into the main NuGet package using specific profile.

You **should only** be including the `ServiceStack.Client` package in your project. So remove all references to ServiceStack in your project, clean the build, and add just `ServiceStack.Client`.

If you reference `ServiceStack.Client.Pcl` was well as `ServiceStack.Client` you will get a conflict.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have included ServiceStack.Client by typing "Install-Package ServiceStack.Client" in the package manager console. Additionally I have downloaded ServiceStack.Client.Pcl.dll and included it as a reference. Unfortunately the error message remains the same.

Comment: @George The point I was making is DON'T download and include `ServiceStack.Client.Pcl.dll`. ONLY reference `ServiceStack.Client`. `ServiceStack.Client.Pcl` must NOT be included, because it will conflict with the reference to `ServiceStack.Client` which now includes the iOS requirement built in. So forget the PCL library.

Comment: I did a mistake in the commend above! By mistake I wrote that I have downloaded ServiceStack.Client.Pcl.dll rather than ServiceStack.Pcl.iOS.dll. Sorry about this. So, after installing ServiceStack.Client, I have references to ServiceStack.Client, ServiceStack.Interfaces and ServiceStack.Text. Lastly a reference to ServiceStack.Pcl.iOS which is required in order to use "IosPclExportClient.Configure()"